# Elastichsearch deep pagination? Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [2000000] but was [22863460]

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination, full-text-search

I am using **elasticsearch** as a backend to store my application data. Storing data for last **120 days** with **monthly index pattern**. On my application's **Live Feed Section** i am showing data for mentioned date range.  For smaller set of documents i am able to send search request through panel. But in case of large data sets i am getting `index.max_result_window` limit exception

**Usage Configuration:**

- Currently Using simple elasticsearch`_search` query to fetch the data.
- Using `7.16.3` Elasticserch version
- Using GCP cloud Servers with Configuration of `CPU: 24Core, Memorty: 64GB & Cloud Storage: 5TB SSD`

**Current Elasticsearch Index & Size**

```
[root@in-es1 inwo]# curl -sX GET "localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v" | grep -i 2023| grep -i mobina
green  open   mobina202308                    5sHwv5NCRByFCS9gqefoBQ  15   0  283082385     26944611     61.2gb         61.2gb
green  open   mobina202307                    CmfWRpG6QZeJb3ZxmFnkAg  15   0  349441977     34435364     78.2gb         78.2gb
green  open   mobina202306                    3ieIwZXEQm6N3LbBoVZ4cg  15   0  373633780     40187267       82gb           82gb

green  open   mobina202311                    fnjdR5gARgueMt_t4R8oUg  15   0  583877476     31202508    134.6gb        134.6gb
green  open   mobina202310                    UF8t3E2dSmKJG-RdlK1T8w  15   0  651684388     41789314    155.7gb        155.7gb
green  open   mobina202312                    UVSYysM2STWEie7aX4SZLg  15   0  647298624     42619380    149.8gb        149.8gb
[root@in-es1 inwo]#
```

**Elasticsearch Query**

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/mobina-202312/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{ 
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "status"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "adate": {
                            "gte": "20231204",
                            "lte": "20231204"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "track_total_hits": true,
    "sort": {
        "timestamp": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    },        
    "size": "10",
    "from": 22863450,
    "_source": [
        "rcpt_email",
        "adate",
        "fromaddress",
        "atime",
        "msize",
        "udate",
        "status",
        "dsndate",
        "remarks",
        "rdom",
        "subject",
        "custom_data",
        "tags",
        "csch_time",
        "sch_time",
        "message_id",
        "counts_opens",
        "opens",
        "batch_id"
    ]
}'
```

**Live Feed Pagination Counter**
[image]

**Live Feed Pagination On Requesting Last page**
[image]

**Elasticsearch Exception**

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 15,
    "successful" : 14,
    "skipped" : 14,
    "failed" : 1,
    "failures" : [
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "mobina-202312",
        "node" : "wsfxNBBVQDCdxNGabksAnA",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason" : "Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [2000000] but was [22863460]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level setting."
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

**Problem Summary**

- Documents count in single index is above `20 million`
- If we multiply doc count for last 120 days then its almost more than `60 million`
- Pagination is working for initial requests as per max_result_window limit. i.e `2000000`
- If i request last page, elasticsearch throwing exception causing no result sets.

**Tried Solutions**

- Tried with increasing limit of max_result_window but considering performance imapact its not possible solution
- Tried Search After but not aware of Search Before like pagination from start to end, end to start and in between with random order.

**Expectations**

- Deep pagination should work as expected, at any number of page like 0 to end/last page.